# how to subtract Object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement, iterator

can you tell me how to subtract the object value,
let say that I have an Object for the item and has stock

```
 let theObj = {
    pants: [
       {
       color: "Pink",
       stock: 80,
       price: 30.99
       } 
           ]
    };
```

that is just not many values and keys, how about that Object has a lot of data?

for illustrations :
if the user wants to buy the pant and after he/she pick what he/she wanted, that object will be subtracted by what user want to buy how many they want, and it will be subtracted if other users buy that pants and that colo until run out,
I hope this makes sense

i hope my question and illustration make sense for you

```js
let theObj = {
    pants: [
       {
       color: "Pink",
       stock: 80,
       price: 30.99
       } 
           ]
    };
    
const theData = theObj["pants"].map(e => e.stock - 1)
console.log(theData)
console.log(theObj) // nothing change when i subtact it
```

Comment: map doesn't change the Object

Comment: `theObj["pants"].map(e => --e.stock)`

Comment: so how ? show we should call the theObj.pants["stock"] - 1 ?@LucaKiebel

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use MAP since it does not change anything. Use forEach or similar loop

```js
let theObj = {
  pants: [{
    color: "Pink",
    stock: 80,
    price: 30.99
  }]
};

theObj["pants"].forEach(e => e.stock -= 1)
console.log(theObj)
```

You perhaps mean this?

```js
let theObj = {
  pants: [{
    color: "Pink",
    stock: 80,
    price: 30.99
  }]
};

const purchase = { pants: { color: "Pink", quantity:2 }} // your user changes this

// this can be in a function

const item = Object.keys(purchase)[0];
theObj[item].forEach((e) => { if (e.color==purchase[item].color) e.stock -= purchase[item].quantity })
console.log(theObj)
```

Comment: why the result of the data is undefined ?? that is just a short object variable for my example, how about if our items a lot ?? should we use the function ? and using that forEach in the function?

Comment: What result? I do not return anything anymore. Please reload

Comment: how about if we have a lot of items and when user want to pick it and the stock will be subtracted? could we use  if statement and then use that forEach to subtract ?  @mplunjan

Comment: is that make sense ?? @mplungjan

Comment: You mean  `const getQuantityNonOrganic = fruits["non_organic"].map(e => e.quantity)` - you need reduce if you want to count more than one item in an array

Comment: on this line : 

const ourSell = (user, stock, kindOfFruits, fruit) => {
  if (kindOfFruits == "organic" || kindofFruits == "non_organic") {
    if (kindOfFruits == "organic") {
      if( fruit == getFruitUserOrganic[0] || fruit == getFruitUserOrganic[1] || fruit == getFruitUserOrganic[2] ){
        console.log(`thank you this ${fruit} will add to cart now `)
        if( fruit == getFruitUserOrganic[0]){
          getQuantityOrganic[0]
        }
      } else{
        console.log(`sorry this ${fruit} run out in our store`)
      }
    }
  }
 
}

Comment: on the last line , the function @mplungjan sir

Answer (score 1):

instead `.map` you should do `.forEach`

```js
let theObj = {
        pants: [
           {
           color: "Pink",
           stock: 80,
           price: 30.99
           } 
               ]
        };
        
theObj["pants"].forEach(e => e.stock -= 1)
    
console.log(theObj)
```

Comment: Beat you by 15 seconds ;)

Comment: Now this is identical to mine ;)

Comment: @rlemon yeah you are right, I have updated my answer

Comment: @mplungjan haha what you want men :)?

Comment: THERE CAN BE ONLY ONE! ;)

Comment: how about if we have a lot of items and when user want to pick it and the stock will be subtracted? could we use  if statement and then use that forEach to subtract ?  @Artyom

Comment: what unique?? i just want  to subtract the value of stock, so if another user want to pick that stock, it will keep subtract till run out

Comment: yeah if you will have a lot of data you need to check from which object you need to  subtract, you can use for that array indexes, but if you have unique values in your object it will be better to check by those values

Comment: do you mean like this :
IF user choose this "item"
``we loop it ans then if this item choosed by user``
then that item stock will be subtract, 
do we use a return if itis in function or make another variable ? @Artyom

Comment: @ZrClassic yeah exactly, if you need new array you can return it, if you don't need new array you shouldn't return because it will update data by reference

Comment: i mean could we use if-then loop it if the user chooses the item what they want and then subtract that item's stock?? @Artyom

Comment: you should use if inside `.forEach` loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function and generalize it. Iterate through all the keys and check if the value is an object, if object then call the same function(recursion) , if the value is an array then iterate that array and recursively call the same function passing different object

```js
let theObj = {
  pants: [{
    color: "Pink",
    stock: 80,
    price: 30.99
  }]
};

function doOp(keyName, obj) {
  for (let keys in obj) {
    // check if current value is an array
    if (Array.isArray(obj[keys])) {
      obj[keys].forEach(function(item) {
        // call the same function and pass the objecr
        doOp(keyName, item);
      })
    } else if (typeof obj[keys] === 'object' && typeof obj[keys] !== null) {
      doOp(keyName, obj[keys])
    } else if (keys === keyName) {
      obj[keys] = obj[keys] - 1
    }
  }
}

doOp('stock', theObj)
console.log(theObj)
```

I am expecting the result to be

```
let theObj = {
  pants: [{
    color: "Pink",
    stock: 79,
    price: 30.99
  }]
};
```

Comment: is this the faster and great way ?